# Small unreadable toolbar icons of QGIS 2.16.3

Tags: qgis

I have encountered with problem of small icons of toolbar of QGIS 2.16.3. I have ASUSS with high resolution (3200x1800). Changing resolution did not help. Also to apply solution by Dan Antonielli (http://www.danantonielli.com/adobe-app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix/) did not help as well. May be anybody solved the problem?

Answer (score 11):

I also have a HiDPI screen and no problem with too small toolbar icons. Toolbar icon size can be configured in Settings | Options | General with sizes ranging from 16 to 64 pixels:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate so much! The matter was icon size options were hidden in the pop up settings window. If you do not know where they must be, you never guess.